# Does LRCK have to oscillate in an I2S system?

Tags: dac, i2s

I'm working on a audio function generator using the PCM 1795 DAC. I only need a single output channel for my design. Can I just pull LRCK low or high permanently for the sake of maintaining design simplicity? Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LRCK cycling is required to indicate the framing of the data even with only one channel.

Effectively the LRCK indicates the position of the MSB of a word (in some styles offset by one bit position).

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use LRCK. It is used to identify the beginning of the frame, as well as separate the left and right audio samples. See page 19 of the data sheet[1](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1795.pdf)